# VB.NET crystal report form throwing up error. reportclass, report definition and reportsections are allnot defined

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

im using vs 2010. I installed crystal reports and its runtime library, it all worked well and the crystal report viewer appeared in toolbox. however, after i created my report design, the **Report vb file** threw up 13 errors:

Error   14  'DataDefinition' is not a member of Application

Error   2   Base class 'CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportClass' specified for class 'PrintReceipt' cannot be different from the base class 'System.Windows.Forms.Form' of one of its other partial types.

Error   14  'DataDefinition' is not a member of 'P.A.S_Sales_and_inventory.PrintReceipt'.

Error   4   property 'ResourceName' cannot be declared 'Overrides' because it does not override a property in a base class.

etc...

I checked all the forums, and all what i can see as a solution is to change the target framework of my application to 4 instead of 4 client profile. **i already did** but my problem wasn't solved out!

please any help

Answer (score 0):

i uninstalled Crystal report and its runtime for the third time then installed it. it finally worked :)